# Joining bytes to create ctypes.c_char_p string

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to upgrade some code written in python2, so that it works in python3 and still works in python2. This is the code snippet in question that works under python2:

```
import ctypes
import struct

class Ethernet(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [('dst', ctypes.c_char_p)]

    def __init__(self, packet):
        (dst, ) = struct.unpack('!6s', packet[:6])

        self.dst = ':'.join(['%02x' % (ord(octet), ) for octet in dst])

def main():

    p = b'\xab\xad\xba\xbe\x0f\xe9'
    e = Ethernet(p)

    if b"ab:ad:ba:be:0f:e9" == e.dst:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problems start when I move to python3 i get this warning for the same code:

```
File "test2.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
  self.dst = ':'.join(['%02x' % (ord(octet), ) for octet in dst])

  TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

So obviously this code doesn't work as it is in python3.

The only way I can seem to get it to work is like this :

```
    try: # Python 3
        self.dst = b':'.join([struct.pack('bb', ord('{:x}'.format((octet >> 4) & 0xf)), ord('{:x}'.format((octet >> 0) & 0xf))) for octet in dst])
    except TypeError: # Python 2
        self.dst = ':'.join(['%02x' % (ord(octet), ) for octet in dst])
```

Which is very messy, but every which way I try it it the *fields* definition of ctypes.c_char_p that blocks anything simple.

Is there a better way to do this that is a single line that works in both python2 and python3 (no exceptions needed)

Comment: 2.6+ has the `bytearray` type, which iterates as integers. It also has `b''` literals. For the formatting part in Python 3 you can use a string and then encode it, which is harmless in Python 2. For example: `dst = bytearray(packet[:6]);` `self.dst = b':'.join([('%02x' % octet).encode('ascii') for octet in dst])`

Comment: That seemed to do the job, a lot cleaner and plays well between python2 and python3.  Thanks for that, I don't see how I mark this as the answer though.

Comment: Formatting `bytes` is a common problem in Python 3. Did you search for previously answered questions? BTW, in 3.5 `b'%02x' % n` is finally implemented (i.e. `bytes.__mod__` is defined).

Comment: Yes the bytes problem I have hit a few times, this was the first I really got stuck on. As to previous questions I tried, but the bounding issue if ctypes I hadn't seen before, and isn't covered.  Also isn't % in strings supposed to be on its way to being deprecated? I have been trying to move to .format for a while, but % still seems in play.

Comment: No, C-style % formatting is not going to be deprecated. Like I said, it's even being added to the `bytes` type in 3.5 (by popular demand). There won't be a `bytes.format` method to parallel `str.format`. Supporting that with full generality would require a new dunder method such as `__format_bytes__`.

Comment: Interesting, yes the c-style formatting did seem to be here for the long haul, I didn't realise the byte support for % had been added, thanks for the heads up, it's been very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I can't mark the correct answer as such but [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) response is what worked for me:

2.6+ has the `bytearray` type, which iterates as integers. It also has `b''` literals. For the formatting part in Python 3 you can use a string and then encode it, which is harmless in Python 2. For example:

```
dst = bytearray(packet[:6]); 
self.dst = b':'.join([('%02x' % o).encode('ascii') for o in dst])`
```

–  [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) Jul 16 at 15:39

Comment: Comments aren't answers. I wanted you to search for answers to similar questions since it's a common problem in Python 3. I don't feel like doing the leg work myself. The "bounding issue [of] ctypes" isn't relevant to this question.